# Wordpress Customizer Options Not Working Properly

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a Wordpress customizer option to show breadcrumbs. No matter what it is set to, it always shows. It shouldn't show if set to none.

Functions.php

```
/* MAIN SETTINGS - Breadcrumb Setting */
$wp_customize->add_setting('swag_main_breadcrumb_top_homepage', array(
    'default' => 'main-breadcrumb-top-homepage-none'
));
$wp_customize->add_control('swag_main_breadcrumb_top_homepage', array(
    'label' => 'Top Breadcrumb On Homepage',
    'section' => 'swag_main_design_section',
    'active_callback'  => 'main_show_breadcrumb_settings_callback',
    'type' => 'select',
    'choices' => array(
        'main-breadcrumb-top-homepage-none' => __('None'),
        'main-breadcrumb-top-homepage-design-1' => __('Design 1'),
        'main-breadcrumb-top-homepage-design-2' => __('Design 2'),
        'main-breadcrumb-top-homepage-design-3' => __('Design 3'),
    )
));

/* MAIN SETTINGS - Breadcrumb Setting */
$wp_customize->add_setting('swag_main_breadcrumb_top_otherpage', array(
    'default' => 'main-breadcrumb-top-otherpage-none'
));
$wp_customize->add_control('swag_main_breadcrumb_top_otherpage', array(
    'label' => 'Top Breadcrumb On Otherpage',
    'section' => 'swag_main_design_section',
    'active_callback'  => 'main_show_breadcrumb_settings_callback',
    'type' => 'select',
    'choices' => array(
        'main-breadcrumb-top-otherpage-none' => __('None'),
        'main-breadcrumb-top-otherpage-design-1' => __('Design 1'),
        'main-breadcrumb-top-otherpage-design-2' => __('Design 2'),
        'main-breadcrumb-top-otherpage-design-3' => __('Design 3'),
    )
));
```

Header.php

```
$swag_main_breadcrumb_top_homepage = get_theme_mod('$swag_main_breadcrumb_top_homepage');
if (isset($swag_main_breadcrumb_top_homepage) && $swag_main_breadcrumb_top_homepage=='') {
$swag_main_breadcrumb_top_homepage ='';
}

$swag_main_breadcrumb_top_otherpage = get_theme_mod('$swag_main_breadcrumb_top_otherpage');
if (isset($swag_main_breadcrumb_top_otherpage) && $swag_main_breadcrumb_top_otherpage=='') {
$swag_main_breadcrumb_top_otherpage ='';
}

<?php
        if (is_front_page()) {
                if (isset($swag_main_breadcrumb_top_homepage) && $swag_main_breadcrumb_top_homepage !='main-breadcrumb-top-homepage-none') {
                        swag_breadcrumb();
                }
        } else {
                if (isset($swag_main_breadcrumb_top_otherpage) && $swag_main_breadcrumb_top_otherpage !='main-breadcrumb-top-otherpage-none') {
                        swag_breadcrumb();
                }
        }
?>
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: I think get_theme_mod('$swag_main_breadcrumb_top_homepage') should be get_theme_mod('swag_main_breadcrumb_top_homepage'). Beacuse of $ it may not work correctly.

Comment: @DhananjayKyada throws a fatal error if I do that

Comment: No, it should not throw a fatal error because we need to pass setting name in "get_theme_mod()". If it is throwing an exception then please paste here.

Comment: @DhananjayKyada your right, my mistake. I removed it from the wrong bit. Didn't fix it though. To me everything looks right, but still doesn't work.

Comment: @DhananjayKyada I found some typos that I made after I made this post. With your help, this issue is resolved. Put this as your answer and I will choose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a typo mistake in your code. For example

`get_theme_mod('$swag_main_breadcrumb_top_otherpage')`

should be like

`get_theme_mod('swag_main_breadcrumb_top_otherpage')`.